# Should I remove the hard-science tag from this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/60239/how-to-harness-jupiters-gravitational-energy) yesterday and the answers have been numerous (this site is awesome).

However, my question is not very well documented and the answers are mostly qualitative, and I don't think they fit the hard-science requirement.

Now, I still wish to incite hard-science answers, but I think it would be more representative of both the question and the answers to switch to `science-based`. I am ready to do some research and improve my question if necessary. Not that I'm downgrading my expectancy much, I have no work depending on this. I mostly wish to avoid a misleading tag.

Is it indeed science-based? What should I do?

UPDATE: I'm thinking about adding a bounty for best hard-science answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the moderator who added the post notice to a fair portion of the answers . . . I'm going to say yes.

Generally, I'm not a fan of retagging (either adding or removing) the [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag after you've gotten answers to the question, but I do feel that the latter is better than the former, as you're not really invalidating any answers. In this case, most of the answers aren't really [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science), either, so it's not as if someone wrote a really fantastic answer that deserves a million upvotes whose work has gone for naught. I don't mean to disparage the answers already there - some are good - but there's nothing I would consider an exemplary [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) answer.

Speaking of which, 6/13 answers currently have the post notice; several others don't have it simply because I didn't see them yet. I do believe that the question can be answered using [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) - honestly, calculating energy transferred through tidal dissipation is not that hard, and I'm a little disappointed nobody actually did the computations - but I also believe that there's a point at which maybe it's better to accede to mass opinion, which currently seems to be that the tag is not needed, for whatever reason. Some of the ideas are interesting, but don't necessarily admit a [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) explanation.

For instance, yesterday James (in chat) had an idea involving the gravitational pull on fluids, but he didn't know how to do the calculations (neither did I; my response: "Fluid mechanics? Away with ye!"). You'd have to ask him, but I think he was dissuaded from the tag, and might have posted an answer if he could have dropped the math.

So, though I say it a bit regrettably, yes, I think it might be good to drop the tag from the question. If you do, flag the question for mod attention using the custom flag, and one of us will remove all the post notices.

Comment: You pretty much sum up my thinking. I'll wait till tomorrow to see if an other alternative is proposed.

Comment: For what it's worth I agree :)